# Netmiko maintain the connection linux

Tags: python-3.x, ssh, netmiko

I am a beginner in terms of netmiko, I found out that I can use it to send commands via ssh to other Linux machines. I have done a lot of progress, but it is a bug that I can not understand, everything is going well, but when I trying to configure something is terminating the connection without finishing. I am doing this in parallel processing and as you can see here the fist error, terminating the connection without finishing:

```
Configure Apache
sudo su
root@beef-server:/home/beef# 
sudo apt install -y software-properties-common 2>&1 | tee -a /var/log/remote_instalation/instalation.log

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
```

But sometimes is not going even to this part as you can see it in the second process.

The code is like this:

Main file, which is taking commands from the user:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('1) File configuration \n2) Commands \n ')
    choose = int(input('Please select the mode that you want to input the commands: '))
    
    # print(choose)
    
    if choose==1 :
        
        filename = input('Please input the filename with the full path: ')
        params = get_hosts(filename)
        print(params)
        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
            try:
                results = [executor.submit(default_instalation,params[param]) for param in params ]
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
            
            for result in results:
                print(result)
```

The default instalation file:

```
from netmiko import linux

from .instalation.add_repositories import  AddRepository
from .instalation.apache.install_apache import intall_apache
from .instalation.apache.configure_apache import AppacheConfiguration
from .instalation.rabbitmq.rabbitmq import rabbitmq
from .instalation.etcd.etcd import etcd

def default_instalation(param)->str:
    
    
    device = linux.LinuxSSH(
            ip=param['ip'],
            username=param['username'],
            password=param['password'],
            secret=param['secret'],
            device_type=param['device_type'],
            verbose=True,
            keepalive=1,
            )
    

    
    outputen = device.enable(cmd="sudo su",pattern="password")
    print(outputen)
    
    
    outputen = device.send_command("sudo mkdir /var/log/remote_instalation")
    print(outputen)
    

    output = device.send_command('set -e 2>&1 | tee -a /var/log/remote_instalation/instalation.log')
    print(output)
    
    add_repo = AddRepository(conn=device)
    print(add_repo.add_repositories())
    
    
    apache_conf = AppacheConfiguration(conn=device)
    print(intall_apache(device))
    print(apache_conf.configure_apache())
```

AddRepository class:

```
from netmiko import linux

class AddRepository:
    def  __init__(self, conn):
        self.conn = conn

    def add_repositories(self)->str:
        
        print ("Adding repositories")
        
        commands = ['sudo apt install -y software-properties-common 2>&1 | tee -a /var/log/remote_instalation/instalation.log',
                    'sudo add-apt-repository cloud-archive:antelope -y 2>&1 | tee -a /var/log/remote_instalation/instalation.log'
                    ]
        
        print(self.conn.send_config_set(commands))
        
        return "[+] Repository has been added"
```

ApacheConfiguration class:

```
class AppacheConfiguration:
    def __init__(self, conn):
        self.conn = conn

    def configure_apache(self)->str:
        
        print("Configure Apache")
        
        outputen = self.conn.enable(cmd="sudo su",pattern="password")
        print(outputen)
        
        commands = [
            """echo "ServerName controller" >>/etc/apache2/apache2.conf 2>&1 | tee -a /var/log/remote_instalation/instalation.log""",
            """sudo cat >/etc/apache2/sites-available/keystone.conf <<END
                  A lot of configuration that works
            END
            """,
            """a2ensite keystone.conf 2>&1 | tee -a /var/log/remote_instalation/instalation.log""",
            ]
        
        print(self.conn.send_config_set(commands))
        
        self.conn.send_command("""sudo systemctl restart apache2.service 2>&1 | tee -a /var/log/remote_instalation/instalation.log""",cmd_verify=False)
    
        return ("[+] Apache has been configured")
```

Now the issue is the "a2ensite keystone.conf 2>&1 | tee -a /var/log/remote_instalation/instalation.log" is not even executed.

Do you have any suggestion what can I do in this situation?

Comment: All other commands are executed? Not sure if `<<END` works well in this setup. Could you try it with `echo "..." > file`?